# How can i make a TextField validation work in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a little problem and I do not know how can I fix it .

I have a textfield, and when the textfield does not meet a certain criteria, I want to display a text underneath. All is working fine, except that the error text underneat is displayed just when the view is reloaded, like exit from the view and entering again.

I will put the code below so you can look at it :

```
struct EntryField: View {
    var placeHolder: String
    var prompt: String
    @Binding var field: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
         TextField(placeHolder, text: $field).autocapitalization(.none)
            Text(prompt)
        }
    }
}
```

```
class VerifyFieldsViewModel : ObservableObject {
    
    @ObservedObject var coreDataViewModel = CoreDataViewModel()
    func isValid() -> Bool {
        guard coreDataViewModel.savedDetails.first?.firstName?.count ?? 0 > 0 else {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    
    var isFirstNameValid : String {
        if isValid() {
       return ""
        
        } else {
        return "Complete first name"
        }
    }
}
```

```
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct DeliveryView: View {
    @ObservedObject var verifyFieldsViewModel = VerifyFieldsViewModel()
    @StateObject var coreDataViewModel = CoreDataViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        let firstName = Binding(
            get: {coreDataViewModel.savedDetails.first?.firstName ?? ""},
            set: {coreDataViewModel.savedDetails.first?.firstName = $0})

        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
               
                    Text("Nume")
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                    EntryField(placeHolder: "Popescu", prompt: verifyFieldsViewModel.isFirstNameValid , field: firstName)
                        .onSubmit {
                            coreDataViewModel.saveContext()
                        }
        }
       
    }
}
}
```

That's the code. Hope you can help me with this problem.
Thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since you need to frequently update the error message then your prompt property in EmptyField should be Binding, otherwise you'll need to refresh the view.

```
@Binding var prompt: String
```

and isFirstNameValid becomes:

```
var isFirstNameValid: String {
    get {
        if isValid() {
            return ""
        }else {
            return "Complete first name"
        }
    }
    set {
    }
}
```

Or you can directly use the model in EmptyField, full code:

```
struct EntryField: View {
    var placeHolder: String
    @ObservedObject var verifyFieldsViewModel: VerifyFieldsViewModel //edited here
    @Binding var field: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            TextField(placeHolder, text: $field).autocapitalization(.none)
            Text(verifyFieldsViewModel.isFirstNameValid) //edited here
        }
    }
}

class VerifyFieldsViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @ObservedObject var coreDataViewModel = CoreDataViewModel()
    func isValid() -> Bool {
        guard coreDataViewModel.savedDetails.first?.firstName?.count ?? 0 > 0 else {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    var isFirstNameValid : String {
        if isValid() {
            return ""
        }else {
            return "Complete first name"
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct DeliveryView: View {
    @ObservedObject var verifyFieldsViewModel = VerifyFieldsViewModel()
    @StateObject var coreDataViewModel = CoreDataViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        let firstName = Binding(
            get: {coreDataViewModel.savedDetails.first?.firstName ?? ""},
            set: {coreDataViewModel.savedDetails.first?.firstName = $0})
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Nume")
                    .foregroundColor(.orange)
                EntryField(placeHolder: "Popescu", verifyFieldsViewModel: verifyFieldsViewModel, field: firstName) //edited here
                    .onSubmit {
                        coreDataViewModel.saveContext()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on your solution, i get this error now `
  EntryField(placeHolder: "Popescu", prompt: $verifyFieldsViewModel.isFirstNameValid , field: firstName)
`

Error : Cannot assign to property: 'isFirstNameValid' is a get-only property

Comment: Check my updated answer!

Comment: Thank you, is working very well. But I have an issue. If I have 2 EntryField in my Delivery View, how can I display different "error" underneat the text, because this is case is only for ` Text(verifyFieldsViewModel.isFirstNameValid) `

Comment: I see the problem now, well then we should use a modified version of my old answer where we simply add get and set to isFirstNameValid which would solve the issue at hand. I just updated my answer! Sorry for the confusion.